# I want to create the website in wordpress.In that i want to create the header where header is static but quotes inside header change dynamically

Tags: wordpress

I am new in wordpress I want to create the website like http://www.robinacourtin.com/ this.In this header lookes static  but the quotes inside the header is changing dynamically when we change the page(plz check the website of "http://www.robinacourtin.com/" ).How do I work on it.

Comment: You really want to look for some theme which has this type of design and find a plugin which does this dynamic quote thing. I am sure there will be some plugin out there.

Comment: yes I got the quotes collection plugin which work fine

Comment: You could just use a custom field for the quotes on each page

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please note that asking general questions like this is discouraged, questions should only be posted after you have researched your issue and should include your attempts so far along with the relevant code in a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Please also read [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) and [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)